# Bootstrap dropdown-toggle is not working in latest Chorme 58.0.2988.0

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

Bootstrap `dropdown-toggle` is not working in the latest Chorme 58.0.2988.0. `document-toogle` it refers acc.min.css and ace.min.js. Since menu toggle is not working in website. But this class is working in Chrome - Version 57.0.2987.133.

Can any one help me on this issue?

Comment: post the code so that others can understand what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by update the below ace js file. It is working now.

https://github.com/bopoda/ace/blob/master/assets/js/ace.min.js